# circulant matrix inversion using fast fourier transform

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, fast-fourier-transform

I am Huda.  May I know, if I have a circulant matrix, can I calculate its inversion using fast fourier transform? If yes, I really need an explanation.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Huda.  Wikipedia has a [brief explanation here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix#In_linear_equations) of how the discrete Fourier transform (or the fast Fourier transform if you prefer) can be used to invert a circulant matrix.  Does that suffice for you, or would you like further clarification?

Comment: It is too general for me. I prefer to have some examples and it is better if you can share with me any books that I can refer to. Thank you